# Print the number of .txt files in the given directory

Tags: files, directory

I want to print the number of `.txt` files in the given directory.

If a directory have 5 `.txt` files so the output will be like:

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt
```

and after that when I check the list, all the files will be shown including .txt.

Please kindly help.

Comment: "I want to print the number of .txt files" and "the output will be like 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt" are conflicting statements. Also, most likely this has been asked before, have you searched something? If yes, please add it to your question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose that we have 5 files in a directory and you want to show only those text files: 1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt

So you have to only do the above :

```
ls -1 <directory_path_where_you_have_your_txt_files> | grep '\.txt$'
```

And to print the total number of these text files, just type the following :

```
ls -1 <directory_path_where_you_have_your_txt_files> | grep '\.txt$' | wc -l
```

Or simply as suggested by @steeldriver  :

```
ls -1 <directory_path_where_you_have_your_txt_files>/*.txt
```

Comment: Why a down vote ?

Comment: Yes correct "ls *.txt" is simpler and will consume less and also for the $ so it will match only those ending with txt . But for the backslash  why it's used in your grep ?

Comment: Yes true i forgot so escaping dot will consider it as a simple char. Thanks

Comment: You need to use `ls -d`. If you don't, and if any of the names that matches `*.txt` is a directory, then the contents of that directory would be listed, which is not what is asked for. Also, the simplest way to produce the output that the user asks for is by using `echo *.txt`.  You have not addressed how to get the count of files, and how to distinguish _files_ from directories and other filetypes (there may be directories matching the pattern `*.txt` too).  Also, don't use line oriented text tools to work on filenames, as filenames may contain newlines.

Comment: Did you understood the question : he said if a directory have 5 txt files not what you are supposing and also the count is on the second snippet, so please remove your downvote. i've seen lot of you not addressing complex answers.

Comment: None of your commands will give the expected output as `ls -1` forces the output of filenames to be separated by newlines. Also, if the directory contains files with newlines in their names, then your counting of the names will be wrong.  But this is all a bit moot as we don't actually know what they want. Do they, fore example, want the output to always be `1.txt 2.txt` if there are two `.txt` files, regardless of their names. Also, it's unclear how you address their "all the files will be shown including .txt".

Comment: it's okay for the inline outout that he want but i dont get you in the new line things because based on his supposition there is only {1..5}.txt files that resides on this directory and i don't see any new line in the filenames.